# How can I check if the message author has guild ownership using Discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am creating a backup bot and I do not want people to have rights to make or load a backup unless they are the guild owner

I am using this at the moment.

```
 if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")){
            return message.channel.send(":x: | You must be an administrator of this server to request a backup!");
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
if (message.guild.ownerId !== message.author.id) return message.channel.send(`You must be the owner of this server.`);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!